# Trouble updating

Tags: apt, updates

When I run `apt-get update` or `apt-get upgrade`, I get the following error messages:

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header  
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run these commands:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```